# xsl:text must not contain child elements

Tags: jquery, xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am getting is error **xsl:text must not contain child elements** while creating the `href` value in anchor tag .here it is n0t created

here is my code
http://xsltransform.net/bwdwsL

```
<a><xsl:attribute name="href">
                  <xsl:text>http://m.timesofindia.com?upcahe=<xsl:value-of select="'dd'"/></xsl:text>
          </xsl:attribute>Next</a>
```

Comment: Please post all the necessary code within your question, not in external links.

Answer (score 1):

Your attribute value is completely static so you can simply use a literal attribute with e.g.

```
<a href="http://m.timesofindia.com?upcahe=dd">Next</a>
```

If you want to compute part of an attribute value with XPath then use [attribute value templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#attribute-value-templates) e.g.

```
<a href="http://m.timesofindia.com?upcahe={'dd'}">Next</a>
```

If you really need to use `xsl:attribute` then with

```
<xsl:attribute name="href">http://m.timesofindia.com?upcahe=<xsl:value-of select="'dd'"/></xsl:attribute>
```

Or with `xsl:text`

```
<xsl:attribute name="href">
  <xsl:text>http://m.timesofindia.com?upcahe=</xsl:text>
  <xsl:value-of select="'dd'"/>
</xsl:attribute>
```

Again, all that only makes sense if your XPath expressions select data from an XML document, not with static strings.